# Calculate 2.5D point cloud from scene

Tags: python, point-clouds

Ich would like to generate a 2.5D point cloud of a scene from the camera's perspective with python. Let's say the camera has a rosolution of [n,m] pixel and as a result I want to have  n*m 3D vectors each starting at the camera and pointing to the surface of the object. I don't expect any code, but please point me in the right direction.

Comment: you could just render the image and take the Z-Depth. From that Z-Depth image you can easily get everything you want (with some coding of course)

Comment: @HenrikD: thanks that works. See also:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105094/get-a-full-numeric-z-depth-from-a-rendered-image